# Android Studio template: Master/Detail Flow missing <kind_name>ListFragment.java

Tags: android, android-studio

I installed Android studio 1.5.1 (the most recent version) and start to learn Master/Detail flow using its template. According to the learning book, the created Master/Detail flow project from the template shall have 4 java class files as:

```
<kind_name>ListActivity.java, 
<kind_name>ListDetailFragment.java 
<kind_name>ListDetailActivity.java 
<kind_name>ListFragment.java
```

but the project missing ListFragment.java. How to resolve this problem.

Sunny

Comment: And.. what does the book state about it? what android studio version was used in the book? more important than, how many files it has, does it work?, what files do your solution have?

Comment: I use the learning book is: Android Studio Development Essentials. I know that the book may use an old version of android studio. I use most recent Android studio 1.5.1. Do you know where I can get the information about how to use Master/Detail flow template with most recent android version. Thanks